# Java Annotation To Insert In Database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I have a database that stores data in the key-value format, for example:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Key            |     Value        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      KEY_FOR_NAME   |     Abhishek     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Currently, to store data in this table, for each key I do something like:

```
String additionalInfoValue = "Abhishek";
AdditionalInfo additionalInfo = new AdditionalInfo(); //entity object
additionalInfo.setKey("KEY_FOR_NAME");
additionalInfo.setSolutionValue(additionalInfoValue);
```

There are a lot of key-value pairs that go into that table, so it leads to a lot of code like the one mentioned above.

What I want to do is to make some annotation like:

```
@StoreInTable("KEY_FOR_NAME")
String additionalInfoValue = "Abhishek";
```

This will save my data in the table and will avoid unnecessary code like the one mentioned above.

I use Spring with Hibernate in my project to make all the entities and database queries (HQL).

Comment: even so, you'll still need to write that code in the handler of the annotation.

Comment: @Stultuske that will mean trading thousand of lines of code for one handler code.

Comment: ?  no, it wouldn't. this can be just as wel achieved with code reuse, just less code than creating the annotation, it's handler and writing the code.

Comment: Why not just a method to which you pass the key and value, which then performs the insert?

Comment: Why not just write a method?

Comment: Well, I think annotation will be simpler in my case compared to a method.

Comment: As it would help to differentiate these variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just a simple Java reflection problem if I understand you correctly. Something like below:

Define `@StoreInTable`:

```
@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface StoreInTable {
    String value();
}
```

Write a function that pack `@StoreInTable` setting for any instance to a list of `AdditionalInfo` :

```
public class FooUtil {

    public static List<AdditionalInfo> packAdditionalInfo(Object instance) throws Exception {
        List<AdditionalInfo> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Field field : instance.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            StoreInTable storeInTable = field.getAnnotation(StoreInTable.class);
            if (storeInTable != null) {
                AdditionalInfo info = new AdditionalInfo();
                info.setKey(storeInTable.value());
                info.setValue(field.get(instance).toString());
                result.add(info);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

To use it , define any class representing key value pair which may be :

```
public class KeyValue {

    @StoreInTable("KEY1")
    String additionalInfoValue1 = "Abhishek";

    @StoreInTable("KEY2")
    String additionalInfoValue2 = "Keshri";
}
```

Then :

```
List<AdditionalInfo> infoList = FooUtil.packAdditionalInfo(new KeyValue());
for(AdditionalInfo info : infoList){
    //save the info one by one , in this case it would save (key=KEY1, value=Abhishek) and (key=KEY2 , value=Keshri)
    entityManage.persist(info);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of something on this line, will try it out!